# iphone X maximum accelerometer and gyroscope frequency

Tags: ios, iphone, accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope

What is maximum frequency of an accelerometer and a gyroscope on an iPhone X available for developers?

I know that some top Android devices have frequencies from 200Hz to 500Hz. For example, Samsung Galaxy S8 has 500Hz, Pixel 2 has 400Hz for both sensors

Answer (score 1):

Well. Unfortunately iPhone developers have only 100Hz frequency for Accelerometer and Gyroscope in SDK